# Custom view and change the size of the child views

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view that extends from FrameLayout. I'd like one of the children to have a size equal to the 20% of the total size as shown in the image.

How can I achieve the imageview to always have this size even if the custom view changes its size in runtime?

[image]

Comment: First of all, there's no image. Also, please, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your view:

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.customView);
```

Then you can get the layoutParams of the `view` calculate 20% of it, and then create a new view which will be 20% of the view.

For example:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
int imgSize = view.getLayoutParams().width * 0.2; //20 % of the width
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(imgSize, imgSize);
//params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;//How to set gravity programmatically
img.setLayoutParams(params);
//Set img attirubutes like src etc.

view.addView(img)
```

Also because you are using a FrameLayout it might be better to create an instance of a LayoutParam first and the set it in `img.setLayoutParams(params)`, because iam sure you want to change the `layout_gravity` of the different views, which you can do in the `params` vairable